# which() for several values

Tags: r, vector

Let's say that we have two vectors:

```
x <- c("1", "5", "8")
y <- c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8")
```

I want to obtain indexes of y in which y equals x.

My code is:

```
x <- c("1", "5", "8")
y <- c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8")
which(y == x) 
> which(y == x)
[1] 1 5
Warning message:
In y == x : longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

And it's kind of logical because those two are not same length, however I have no idea how can I do this without any loop. Do you have any idea how it can be performed ?

Comment: Do you want `which(y %in% x)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this solution. `match` function finds the position of each element of x in y.

```
match(x, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `which(y %in% x)`  as `%in%` will match every element of y with every element of x and return indices